# Is there a Powershell command to get Security groups of Azure repositories?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Is there a Powershell command to get Security groups of Azure repositories ? I am trying to list all the repositories and security groups being used by them for a given project.I am looking for list with Azure Repos and the corresponding security groups on them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install the azure cli via [this link](https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows).

Then run below commands.

`az login`

`az extension add --name azure-devops`

`az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/yourorganizationname project=yourprojectname`

`az devops security group list`

Comment: I have used this before. I want a list with Azure Repos and the corresponding security groups on them.